# Finding the least number of swaps to "sort" a circular array of 1s and 0s

Tags: arrays, algorithm

For example, an array 10110001101110 is given and what the program needs to find is the least number of swaps for it to be all 1s next to each other. In this case it would be 2, by swapping 3 -> 14 and 4 -> 10. By circular array, I mean an array that wraps around, for example 1100001111 would be considered sorted.

The thing that I'm struggling is to find an efficient algorithm for calculating this. I first tried to transform this array into another array that consists of lenghts of strings of same numbers. For example the array given at the start would become 11232131. I noticed that this array always has an even number of elements, but I really don't know what to do with all this, or if this is even a good start to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Count the total number of 1s.  Let **m** be that number
2. Find contiguous region of length **m** that has the most 1s in it
3. The number of 0s in this region is the minimum required swaps.  Each swap will move one 1 into the region and one 0 to the remainder.

Comment: So just to check if I understood correctly, this works because the contiguous region with the most 1s has the least number of "holes" between the 1s that make it not sorted, and by filling those holes I guarrantee that all m 1s are next to each other. This is very clever.